# Is there a cleaner way to convert this string to a dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I get this string from a URL:

```
BEGIN:VCAMERA\r\nMETHOD:PUBLISH\r\nBEGIN:VEVENT\r\n
```

In the end I want to have a dictionary such as `["BEGIN": "VCAMERA"]`.

This is my current implementation:

```swift
let string = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)
let wordArray = string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
var dict = [String: String]()
for keyValue in wordArray {
    let components = keyValue.components(separatedBy: ":")
    if components.count > 1 {
        dict[components[0]] = components.last?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}
```

This code gives the desired output but I wanted to know if there is a cleaner and better way for this.

Comment: This example has the key BEGIN twice, so this code returns `["METHOD": "PUBLISH", "BEGIN": "VEVENT"]`. Is that what your really meant?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question how you want to deal with duplicates, but your code just overwrites them. If so, this is a bit more compact way to do this that is similar to yours:

```
let keyValues = string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
    .map { $0.split(separator: ":") } // Split each element on :
    .compactMap { // return (key, value) pairs, throwing away any malformed rows
        if $0.count > 1 { ($0[0], $0[1]) } else { nil }
    }

// combine pairs into a dictionary, keeping the new value if duplicates are found
let dict = Dictionary(keyValues, uniquingKeysWith: { _, new in new } )
```

I only recommend code like this if your code is very simple and doesn't need to be very robust. In robust code, you'd want to check for errors and deal with them rather than ignoring them this way. Though I suspect that the duplicate keys are going to make you have to change this approach anyway.

If this is actually vCard data, consider [Apple's built-in parser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactvcardserialization/contacts(with:)).